# Can several Python programs safely open a CSV file for reading at the same time?

Tags: python, file, csv, concurrency

I would like to concurrently read a large CSV using several processes, one per CPU core.  Each would be passed the file name and an offset and open the file with

```
file_offset, lines_to_read = ... #Passed to each process

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    f.seek(offset)

    for row_count, row in enumerate(csv.reader(f)):
        if row_count == lines_to_read:
            break

        do_stuff(row[0], row[1], ...)
```

Is it a problem to open a file for concurrent reading, and then zoom to specific offsets with `seek` like this?

Comment: Seems likely that this is an I/O bound task that won't be improved by using multiple processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, multiples processes can read from a file, without corrupting the data read.  One competing `write` may invalidate all of the readers.

However, the utility of doing this depends on your device.  If you have a physical device that needs to await medium rotation or position a read head, your processes will compete with one another for that resource.  Perhaps worse, the prediction and pre-fetch software will likely guess *wrong* in most cases, *degrading* read performance.

If your case is otherwise, perhaps some multi-channel direct-access read medium, then this may, indeed, give you faster performance.  In this case, pay attention to your driver's buffering capabilities, so you don't overload that and merely shift your bottleneck.